# How to apply style changes (such as bold, Italic, color, adding bullets, etc) inside a JTable in Java?

Tags: java, jtable, jtextpane, typography, word-processor

I implement a mini word processor using JTextPane in Java. I created a tool bar that makes me be able to bold, underline, and color the texts which the users can input.

Now I insert a JTable into this JTextPane and I hope to be able to do what I can do outside the table. Can I do that? Using cell renderer and editor to introduce the outside environment? Or use LayerUI to draw a table on the top of the JTextPane? I can draw, but how to edit in the image?

I am a new beginner in Java programming. If you can give me some hints, I would appreciate it very very much!

What I expect is that I can type in the JTable and apply bold, italic, underline and color changes, even add bullets, etc.

Comment: That will not work.  A JTable is not text, it’s a Swing component.  What you can do, however, is [install](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTextPane.html#setEditorKit(javax.swing.text.EditorKit)) an [HTMLEditorKit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html) and then add an HTML table.

Comment: Hello, VGR. Thanks alot for your help. But if I can use HTML to insert a table, how can I apply style changes beyond CSS?

Comment: The same way you do it with other text.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again and again, but I need to clarify it. For other text outside table, I use StyledEditorKit. In other words, how can you bold the text in online table?

Answer (score 0):

A JTable is a component, not text.  It cannot be styled using document styling.

You can, however, install an HTMLEditorKit on your JTextPane, which allows you to add HTML [table](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.1) to your document.  An HTML table is comprised of text, so you can apply styles to it:

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

import javax.swing.text.Style;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;

public class TableInTextPane {
    static void showTextPane() {
        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setEditorKit(
            textPane.getEditorKitForContentType("text/html"));

        Style red = textPane.addStyle("red", null);
        StyleConstants.setForeground(red, Color.RED);

        Style green = textPane.addStyle("green", null);
        StyleConstants.setForeground(green, Color.GREEN);

        textPane.setLogicalStyle(red);

        try {
            textPane.getStyledDocument().insertString(0, "Red text", red);
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        String table =
            "<table border=1>"
            + "<tr><th>Country      <th>Group<th>Position"
            + "<tr><td>Netherlands  <td>A<td>1"
            + "<tr><td>Senegal      <td>A<td>2"
            + "<tr><td>Ecuador      <td>A<td>3"
            + "<tr><td>Qatar        <td>A<td>4"
            + "<tr><td>England      <td>B<td>1"
            + "<tr><td>United States<td>B<td>2"
            + "<tr><td>Iran         <td>B<td>3"
            + "<tr><td>Wales        <td>B<td>4"
            + "</table>";

        int tableStartOffset = textPane.getDocument().getLength();
        try {
            textPane.getEditorKit().read(
                new StringReader(table),
                textPane.getDocument(),
                tableStartOffset);
        } catch (BadLocationException | IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        int tableEndOffset = textPane.getDocument().getLength();

        int caretPosition = textPane.getCaretPosition();

        textPane.select(tableStartOffset, tableEndOffset);
        textPane.setCharacterAttributes(green, false);

        textPane.select(caretPosition, caretPosition);

        showInWindow(textPane);
    }

    private static void showInWindow(JTextPane textPane) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(textPane));
        frame.pack();

        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> showTextPane());
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to express my appreciation to you for spending time on it. It works great from the point of view of HTML kit. I want to email you my program which uses StyledDocument to implement word processor. And I tried to set textPane.setEditorKit(
            textPane.getEditorKitForContentType("text/html"));

Comment: yingzi1.calgary@gmail.com. University of Calgary computer science graduate. Sorry to bother your time. I wrote a word processer using Java and hope to send it to you for the question background, if you are interested in it. Anyway, Thanks a lot!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!I appreciate it very very much.